# Thymeleaf object created from extednd broadleaf processor is made null when using th:each and is accesible only ouside th:each

Tags: spring-mvc, thymeleaf, broadleaf-commerce

Code sample

'someproc' is a custom processor which extends org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.dialect.AbstractModelVariableModifierProcessor from broadleaf platform.

```
<myproc:someproc /> // as a result is objectCreatedInProcessor 
<div th:classappend="${objectCreatedInProcessor==null?'null':'not_null'}></div>
<div th:classappend="${objectAddedToModelAndView==null?'null1':'not_null_1'}></div>

<div th:each="someVar : ${someVars}">
   <div th:classappend="${objectCreatedInProcessor==null?'null':'not_null'}></div>
   <div th:classappend="${objectAddedToModelAndView==null?'null1':'not_null_1'}></div>
</div>

<div th:classappend="${objectCreatedInProcessor==null?'null':'not_null'}></div>
<div th:classappend="${objectAddedToModelAndView==null?'null1':'not_null_1'}></div>
```

As a output result will be :

```
<div class='not_null'></div>
<div class='not_null_1'></div>
<div>
  <div class='null'></div>
  <div class='not_null_1'></div>
  <div class='null'></div>
  <div class='not_null_1'></div>
  <div class='null'></div>
  <div class='not_null_1'></div>   
</div>
<div class='not_null'></div>
<div class='not_null_1'></div>
```

supposing we have three items into $someVars list.

The question is, why is  $objectCreatedInProcessor beeing made NULL into th:each loop. And why variable $objectAddedToModelAndView isn't made NULL, and is accessible into th:each loop?

What I'm doing wrong? Is something what I miss?

**EDIT1** : Closed conditional expression. This wasn't the reason of the problem, it was only a bad code sample.

**EDIT2** : Closed classes into result display.

**EDIT3** : Forogot to mention that $someVars is a variable added from a controller to spring ModelAndView.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as if you are not properly closing the conditionals on your ternary functions.  Add a } after the null and before the ? on each line.

Here is an example ternary from the [docs](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/html/Using-Thymeleaf.html) for reference

```
'User is of type ' + (${user.isAdmin()} ? 'Administrator' : (${user.type} ?: 'Unknown'))
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but the example was written without being tested, but the problem isn't there. The problem is that we have two types of variable, one that is created into spring controller and added to ModelAndView (objectAddedToModelAndView) object (which isn't null into th:each) and one that is added into Processor with the method org.broadleafcommerce.common.web.dialect.AbstractModelVariableModifierProcessor#addToModel (objectCreatedInProcessor) which is made null into th:each loop.